# Single html not showing in fancybox, it's coming as a gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Single html not showing in fancybox, it's coming as a gallery. I want to open them separately, but it's coming as gallery means next, prev button in appearing. I want to hide them or disable them.

Comment: Thanks it resolved. I use rel attribute so it's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Without snippets of your code, it's hard to say. It seems to be covered here: http://fancybox.net/howto

On that page I found the following:

> Note - ID's are meant for a SINGLE instance. If you want to use the
>   same script for all your images/elements then use classes instead.
>
> Note - Galleries are created from elements who have the same "rel"
>   tag, example (on the page)

Regards,

Samuel Peterson